# wp_query same data on every page

Tags: arrays, wordpress, datatable

In my wordpress site where I use ACF, I created an array of arrays with wp_query and imported them into the datatable. It also acts according to the posts_per_page wordpress settings. Currently wordpress is set to 10 impressions per page. I also wrote code in function.php to display the page under the table. 10 data comes into the table. Below is the correct number of pages. The problem starts here. Although the number of pages is correct, I always see the same 10 data when I click on the pages. Where did I make the mistake?

```
    <?php
$show_logo = (!empty($date_or_logo) and $date_or_logo == 'logo') ? true : false;
$posts_per_page = (!empty($number) and intval($number)) ? $number : get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
$current = (!empty($offset) and intval($offset)) ? $offset : 1;
$offset = (!empty($offset) and intval($offset)) ? ( $offset * $posts_per_page ) - $posts_per_page : 0;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'stm_ico_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'meta_key'       => 'end_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => '<',
            'value'   => time(),
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value'   => '',
        ),
    )
);

$args = (!empty($add_args)) ? wp_parse_args($add_args, $args) : $args;

$q = new WP_Query($args);

if ($q->have_posts()): ?>       
    <!-- the loop -->
    
<?php while ($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();

 ?>
            
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">
.............

</td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
</table>



    <!-- end of the loop -->

 <ul class='page-numbers'> 
    <li><?php pagination_bar_venue($q); ?></li>
 </ul>
    <!-- pagination here -->
 
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>



            </div>
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records. per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
            "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, -1], [50, 100, "All"]]
    } );
    
} );
    </script>
```

function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'team_script' );

function pagination_bar_venue( $q ) {

$total_pages = $q->max_num_pages;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

if ($total_pages > 1){
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that your `$offset` never changes value, even if you are on page 4. Can you confirm this?
So this works with the offset, you need to get it from somewhere. Else the query will always use your initial offset value, and display the same items on each page.

Comment: An alternative solution that would be quite simple (if you can deal with Javascript) too, is to get the posts via the REST API with Javascript. Then you could create a single page with an inifinite loading of posts below it. Or even make a more advanced frontend with react that "looks like" it has multiple pages, but actually is a tiny single page application. (this will result in google having issues indexing this page however)

Comment: Yup. I approve. It never changes. Isn't there an easy way other than doing it with javascript?